# Is there a release date of ros 2 or more informations about it?

Tags: ros, ros2, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody!
I just want to know, if there are more informations than these at desing.ros2.org.
Is there a release date?
Is there a community discussing about it?
I just found the presentation at the roscon last september.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208560/is-there-a-release-date-of-ros-2-or-more-informations-about-it?/) by [Rosewood](https://answers.ros.org/users/22353/rosewood/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2015-05-05

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The http://design.ros2.org website captures some of our high level design thoughts, but we (the team at OSRF) found it difficult to have efficient conversations based on such abstract topics. So we'll continue to update the design website as things coalesce, but right now we're working on a first release of ROS 2 which, while not complete, will provide a better foundation on which we can iterate and discuss things with the community. The idea being that since ROS 2 does not disrupt ROS 1 users, it will provide the freedom needed to try new things and find what works and what doesn't work more easily.

Right now (May 2015) we're focused on the ROS Jade release, but there will be more information about ROS 2 after we finish the Jade release. The original plan was to release with Jade, but that's too much work for our small team, so we're handling Jade first then the first version of ROS 2.

In the mean time, there is the prototype itself:

https://github.com/ros2/ros2

Which you can build and have a look at, though you should keep in mind it is not polished at all and is changing quickly, so it's not suitable for general use yet.

Also there is the ROS next generation sig mailing list where some topics have been had, and is where we will continue to discuss things in the future:

http://wiki.ros.org/sig/NextGenerationROS

We're also working hard to get better test coverage across more platforms from the beginning, so that when we start to implement these ideas we can have them working from the get go. You can see "batch" CI jobs which build all of our ROS 2 stuff on different platforms (note these urls will likely break, please comment if they do, and I'll try to update them):

- Linux: http://54.183.26.131:8080/job/ros2_batch_ci_linux/
- OS X: http://54.183.26.131:8080/job/ros2_batch_ci_osx/
- Windows: http://54.183.26.131:8080/job/ros2_batch_ci_windows/

We hope to add more CI for Android and embedded systems in the future, while the system is still small and simple.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rosewood](https://answers.ros.org/users/22353/rosewood/) on 2015-05-08**:
Thanks for your descriptions!
I have just another question belonging to the download of the RTI connext dds.
in
https://github.com/ros2/examples/wiki
it is mentioned, that you can download the packages for Ubuntu, but there is only a readhead download possible. Or do I have to register myself?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-05-08**:
From the two options (OSRF Debian package and official RTI binaries) only the later is available to users. Therefore you have to get an official license from RTI (or a test version) which you have to register for. We can not share the Debian package built at OSRF for license reasons at the moment.

**Comment by [adabrowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/22828/adabrowski/) on 2015-06-17**:
Do you have any estimation on when the ROS 2 release is going to happen? I am trying to plan a long term project around it. I understand it is delayed from the original 6.2015 prediciton. Could you please share any estimates or plan that you have?